# Bootstrap Dropdown events only fire on html element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-mix

So [according to the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#events) I'm supposed to be able to just capture any of the given dropdown events based on the `.dropdown-menu` event.

So I tried to debug with the `*` selector since that doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('*').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev);
    });
});
```

Strangely it shows the root `html` element as the `currentTarget` for the event.

Any attempt to increase specificity in my selector causes it to fail. I can reference the `target` of the successfully-captured event and it won't work anymore. Even if I try using `#sidebar *` (its great-great-... grandparent) as the selector it doesn't work.

I've already tried every single class or attribute selector and it doesn't work. It will only accept it if it's attached to the `html` element.

Is there a way to make this more specific or is this all I'm going to get out of it?

**Update:**

Apparently this is related to Laravel Mix somehow. It has broken *all* jQuery event hooking logic. I can't attach a simple click event to a button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sidebar-toggle').on('click', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev);
    });
});
```

Using `*` as the selector again, I capture the `click` event on the `html` element and nothing else.

I suspect this is a problem of binding on the `global` object instead of the `window` object, but because of past issues getting dependencies to bind correctly, I had no choice but to use it.

My `bootstrap.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import PopperJs from 'popper.js';

global._ = require('lodash');
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
global.axios = axios;
require('bootstrap');

global.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

My `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

mix.disableNotifications();

// almost works but puts the manifest in the wrong place
// mix.setPublicPath('public/assets/build');

let assetDir = 'assets/build';

mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts = `${assetDir}/${mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.fonts}`;
mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.images = `${assetDir}/${mix.config.fileLoaderDirs.images}`;

mix
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new Dotenv()
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
            modules: [
                path.resolve('./node_modules'),
                path.resolve('./resources/js')
            ]
        }
    })

    .js('resources/js/app.js', `public/${assetDir}/js`)
    .extract([
        'axios',
        'bootstrap',
        'jquery',
        'lodash',
        'popper.js'
    ])
    .autoload({
        'axios': ['window.axios', 'axios'],
        'jquery': ['window.jQuery', 'jQuery', 'window.$', '$'],
        'lodash': ['window._', '_'],
        'popper.js': ['window.Popper', 'Popper']
    })

    .version();
```